# Given $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ and a point $x$, $G \cup \{x\}$ is also a $G_{\delta}$ set

Tags: general-topology

I thought of this in many different ways. By definition of $G_{\delta}$, $G=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}U_i$ where $U_i\in G$ are open sets. Then $G \cup \{x\}=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}U_i\cup\{x\}=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}(U_i\cup\{x\})$. So I think will be sufficient to just show that for any $i$,  $U_i\cup\{x\}$ is open. But I don't see how this is valid.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more context?  Are you talking about subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is not specified but I assume it is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, the result is not true if you are talking about a general topological space, so the context matters...

Comment: Hint: Is the set $(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ open?

Comment: Yes, it is in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ I don't think is open. because at point 2, we cannot find a ball that's contained entirely in the $(0,1)\cup\{2\}$.

Comment: Show that $\{x\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set, and show that the union of two $G_\delta$ sets is a $G_\delta$ set. For the latter, it may help to note that a $G_\delta$ set can be expressed as the intersection of a **nested** sequence of open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_i$ be any collection of decreasing open sets such that $\{x\}=\cap_i B_i$, (for examples balls of radius $\epsilon_i=1/i$). Then $G\cup\{x\}=(\cap_i U_i) (\cap_j B_j)=\cap_i(U_i\cap B_i)$